# Is this regular expression vulnerable to DoS?

Tags: denial-of-service, regex

FindBugs flagged the following email address validation regex as vulnerable to DoS:

```
^[\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\.[\w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$
```

Here's an easier to read version that substitutes `CHARS` for `` \w!#$%&'*+/=?`{|}~^- ``:

```
[CHARS]+(?:\.[CHARS]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}
```

Based on my reading of the [OWASP ReDoS page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS), this isn't actually vulnerable. I can't see a way to ambiguously apply the pattern, because the repetition inside the groups doesn't apply to the period character, which ought to result in a canonical application of the pattern.

Have I misunderstood the threat here? Can anyone spot a way to abuse this pattern?

Comment: While not technically off-topic, this is probably more suited for the FindBugs support channel.

Comment: Side note: regex rejects possibly valid addresses: [Top-level domains are valid for addresses](https://serverfault.com/q/721927/87542).  [Addresses are allowed to contain non-ascii characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/760150/812837), which might include the domain (a [more comprehensive list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049502/what-characters-are-allowed-in-an-email-address)).  [Single-character TLDs are valid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7411255/812837).  [More comprehensive regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/812837), but note it won't cover international addresses...

Answer (score 1):

Tricky one! I can't seem to trigger the exponential complexity this `(\.[CHARS]+)*` pattern should introduce. I can make it be a little slow with a huge string (a few megabytes), but I guess that is to be expected with any regular expression. In Python:

```
import time, re
t=time.time()
print(re.match(r'^[\w!#$%&\'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(\.[\w!#$%&\'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$', 'a.'+'xb'*2500000+'test@example.com'))
print(time.time()-t)
t=time.time()
print(re.match(r'^[\w!#$%&\'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(\.[\w!#$%&\'*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$', 'ax'+'.b'*2500000+'test@example.com'))
print(time.time()-t)
```

In the first test, we supply a long string where the `xb` pattern is repeated. This matches just the first part (namely, `[CHARS]+`) and not the second (namely, `(\.[CHARS]+)*)`). The second test does the opposite: it repeats the '.b' pattern which matches the second part a lot of times (where the backtracking should be) and not the first.

As output, you can see the difference in time it takes:

```
0.06872129440307617
0.3483853340148926
```

Both strings are equally long, so the pattern does take some more time.

Usually, one would use the second pattern and then make the end not match, so remove the `.com` part or something. The regex engine would start to backtrack and take exponentially longer with each iteration. I'm not sure why that does not happen here.

So far as I can see, you might be safe by just limiting the input length to a few kilobytes. But I am probably just too stupid to trigger it; using a pattern that is known to be vulnerable is just asking for someone to come along and figure it out ;-)

Comment: "*the exponential complexity this `(\.[CHARS]+)*` pattern should introduce*" > Doesn't the period prevent the complexity? The examples given in the OWASP page look more like `([CHARS]+)*`, which is ambiguous. However in this case, because `CHARS` doesn't include a period as a possible character, I think there is no complexity here?

Comment: @DuncanJones Good point. If I remove the dot and update the test strings accordingly, I can indeed trigger the vuln. So you might be right, but I'd still avoid the regex if possible. (And that's besides the point that email regexes are always faulty/annoying, but that's a different topic covered in other questions on other stackexchange sites.)